# How do I troubleshoot this exception when creating an XmlSerializer object?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xsd, xsd.exe

I downloaded the XML Schema for XML Schemas at http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd.

I then used **XSD.EXE** to create a class from the downloaded file. I called the class `schema.cs`.

I then executed this line of code:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(schema));
```

and got this error:

> The XML element 'annotation' from
>   namespace
>   'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' is
>   already present in the current scope.

How do I find the duplicate element and fix it, without breaking the schema?

Comment: It may be that the exception has a line and position number. Could you add these?

Comment: @Pieter: The exception didn't include a line number, and neither did the inner exception.

Comment: And you have no hint at all what annotation throws? I have looked at the XSD and it looks like there are many scopes where there are multiple annotations.

Comment: @Pieter: No I don't.  That's the basic problem, is visibility.

Comment: @0xA3: I'm trying to read [another XML schema](http://www.spiraltechinc.com/Tmats/Tmats_02-2009.xsd) and analyze it.

Comment: @eschneider: It's big (about 1400 lines of code).  It's easy enough to generate.

Answer (score 1):

I think the generated class has flaws.

I changed the attribute to fix the first error but a new error is discovered.

```
/// <remarks/>
//[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("annotation", typeof(annotation))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Items", typeof(annotation))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("import", typeof(import))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("include", typeof(include))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("redefine", typeof(redefine))]
public openAttrs[] Items {
    get {
        return this.itemsField;
    }
    set {
        this.itemsField = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did use an earlier version of XSD, so I ran it again using the version you are referencing, and did a file compare.  The only differences between the two files were the CompilerGenerated attribute versions, so I didn't bother to test the new file.  Weird.  I'll test the new file and let you know.

Comment: I think the problem still exists (Break on all errors was off). I think the generated class is bad though...

Comment: Yeah, it threw the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Because the annotate elements are just comments, you could try simply filtering all of these out. Just first load the XML into an `XDocument` and remove all annotate elements.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the comments.

Comment: Seen my comment? Do you have line/position numbers of the exception?